# How can I play a file created in OBS?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-recording, software, obs

I downloaded OBS based on an answer [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19151/what-is-the-easiest-no-frills-way-to-produce-a-simple-video-on-windows-10/).

I tested it by selecting "Start Recording" saying a few words, and then "Stop Recording"

I then selected File > Show Recordings, and it opened the This PC > Videos folder in Explorer; the file just created was there, named "2016-08-15 06-11-54.flv"

However, 2-clicking it does not run it in OBS; it wants me to choose an app from the list to use, which, in my case, is "IrfanView" and "Look for an App in the Store"

I tried Irfanview, but the .flv file won't run because Irfanview is apparently lacking a needed Flash .DLL; Flash kind of gives me the fantods, so I let that slide.

Won't OBS play the videos it creates? If so, why doesn't it show up in the list of apps to execute the .flv file? How can I (if possible) get it to run the file?

Comment: Install [Potplayer](http://www.videohelp.com/software/PotPlayer) or [VLC](http://www.videohelp.com/software/VLC-media-player).

Comment: OBS records in mkv format which can be played on almost anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OBS is a video streaming and recording software, not a video player. You will need either find a video player [that will play an .flv file](http://download.cnet.com/s/flv-player/), or switch your settings in OBS to record to a different format, like .mp4, which most video players will be able to playback.